# Как посчитать сумму Measure-Object объектов в PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Как посчитать сумму нескольких Measure-Object объектов в PowerShell - 
например общую сумму сумм WorkingSet и PagedMemorySize всех процессов chrome
что-то типа

```
(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "*chrome.exe"}  \
| Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum  \
| Measure-Object PagedMemorySize -sum).sum / 1MB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(ps firefox|measure -prop workingset,PagedMemorySize -sum).sum
```

или так:
    `ps maxthon|measure -prop workingset,pagedmemorysize -sum|ft property,sum`

Comment: Я имел в виду сумму этих сумм, тоесть, есть ли что-гнибудь проще чем такое: $w = (Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "*firefox.exe"} | Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum
 $p = (Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "*firefox.exe"} | Measure-Object PagedMemorySize -sum).sum
($w + $p) / 1MB

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать, что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "*chrome.exe"} | 
            Select-Object Name,id,@{n='Sum (Mb)';e={(($_ |
            Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum + ($_ |
            Measure-Object PagedMemorySize -sum).sum)/1Mb}}
```